# Move the beginning of a line at its end for each line in Notepad++ or UltraEdit

Tags: replace, notepad++, ultraedit

I have a question using Notepad++ or UltraEdit to copy the first or two first columns of my file and add them to the end. The problem would be easy if my file had regular columns, but it doesn't. Here is what it looks like:

```
18,-8 22 30.82,70 2 34.25,
19,-8 23 10,70 1 42.97,
20,-8 23 40.42,700 51.85,
21,-8 24 10.1,70 0 0.89,
22,-8 24 40.05,69 59 10.09,
...
1318,-7 27 26.82,78 3 16.1,
```

I'd like my id numbers to be copied at the end of each line. I have tried the replace tools, but didn't find the correct expression in order to catch the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 1):

### One possible solution using Notepad++

*Assuming that the columns are separated by commas `,`*:

You can record a macro that will execute the following steps:

- Press the <kbd>Home</kbd> / <kbd>Pos1</kbd> key to set the caret to the first position in the current line
- Search for `,` two times (or how many columns should be copied to the end of the line
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> to select the text from the beginning of the line to the possition of the caret
- Copy the selected text by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
- Press <kbd>End</kbd> to set the caret to the end of the current line
- Paste the copied text to the end of the line by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>
- Move the caret to the next line by pressing <kbd>↓</kbd> (Arrow Down)

Run the macro till the end of the file is reached.

**PS: Always backup your data before running the macro!**

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in Regular Expression search and replace mode:

Find:
`^([0-9]*)(.*)$`

Replace:
`\1\2\1`

### Explanation

`^` and `$` are anchors for the beginning and end of a line, respectively.

`^([0-9]*)` matches from the start of the line until a non-digit is met (in your case, a comma). The 
`(` and `)` make the matched expression available for usage in the Replace box via `\1`.

`(.*)$` matches everything else until the end of the line. Again, the brackets make the matched expression accessible, this time via `\2`.

So, since you want a copy of the first column at the end of the line, you can just do:

Replace: `\1\2\1`

If, instead, you wanted to *move* the first column to the end, you might want to do

Find: `^([0-9]*),(.*)$`

Replace:
`\2\1`

Note the added comma in the find expression. Without it, the comma after the first column of data would get matched as part of the `(.*)` expression and would thus remain at the beginning of your lines when your lines gets replaced with `\2\1`.

**edit** Oops, others have beaten me to (basically) the same answer, but I hope the explanation is helpful nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Find what: `^([0-9]*)(.*)`

Replace with: `\2\1`

[image: Screenshot]

Hope this serves you.

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++:

Open the Replace dialog: Search -> Replace...

To copy the first field to the end:

```
Find what: ^([0-9]+,)(.*)$
Replace with: \1\2\1
```

To move the first field to the end:

```
Find what: ^([0-9]+,)(.*)$
Replace with: \2\1
```